# SQL Server find chains between two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
from | to
-----+-----
 23  | 24
 24  | 25
 25  | 27
 27  | 30
 45  | 46
 46  | 47
 50  | 52
 53  | 60
```

I need a SQL Server query that detect chain's and return min (from) and max (to) in each chain (also chain's with one record):

```
from | to
-----+-----
 23  | 30
 45  | 47
 50  | 52
 53  | 60
```

Comment: you could probably use a recursive CTE. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: You're going to need some sort of looping or recursive structure to deal with this. My first choice would probably be a cursor with a loop that will follow "chains" as you call them. It may not be the most efficient solution, but it would be readable.

Comment: @robbpriestley a recursive cte would be a much better approach for this than a cursor or some other form of looping. We want to avoid loops in t-sql as much as possible because the performance is horrific.

Comment: @SeanLange generally, I agree, but it does absolutely depend on the data size. Also, people who are new to coding are generally more comfortable with looping, so those are factors I am considering here.

Comment: @robbpriestley I would actually say that especially for newer coders that learning set based logic is more important. Let's teach them the best way before they get those terrible practices.

Comment: @SeanLange I think new coders should be encouraged to actually write their own solutions. When they go onto SO, ask a question, and get a fully-written solution that they can copy-paste, and it works, but they have no idea how it works, they haven't learned anything except to depend on other people. That being said, SO is also a wonderful resource, and I do take your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using a recursive CTE.

```
CREATE TABLE #chainLinks(linkFrom INTEGER, linkTo INTEGER);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (23,24);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (24,25);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (25,27);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (27,30);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (45,46);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (46,47);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (50,52);
INSERT INTO #chainLinks VALUES (53,60);

WITH reccte AS
(
    /*Recursive Seed*/
    SELECT linkFrom AS chainStart,
        linkFrom,
        linkTo,
        0 as links
    FROM #chainLinks as chainLinks
    WHERE linkFrom NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT linkTo FROM #chainLinks)

    UNION ALL

    /*Recursive Term*/
    SELECT 
        reccte.chainStart,
        chainLinks.linkFrom,
        chainLinks.linkTo,
        links + 1
    FROM reccte
        INNER JOIN #chainLinks as chainLinks ON reccte.linkTo = chainLinks.linkFrom
)
SELECT chainStart, linkTo AS chainEnd
FROM
    (
        SELECT chainStart, linkFrom, linkTo, links, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY chainStart ORDER BY links DESC) AS rn
        FROM reccte 
    )subrn
WHERE rn = 1;
```

A recursive CTE takes two parts

1. A recursive seed - This is the part above the `UNION` where we determine which records from our table begin the recursion. Here we want any `linkFrom` that isn't also a `linkTo`
2. A recusrive term - This is the part below the `UNION` where we join the cte called `reccte` back to the original table. This part of the CTE iterates over and over again until that join fails.

In here we are also tracking that `links` which is just a counter of the number of iterations we have gone through to get to that outputted record. We keep the highest number of `links` for each starting point `chainStart`.

Here is the working example: https://rextester.com/JWUW57837

Comment: I'm working on that question and you provide the answer quickly, You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If there are branches within the chains it become a little bit more tricky.

In the sample data below, there's a split on `From=12`.
So the result shows 2 chains starting from 14.

> ```
> create table yourtable (
>  [From] int not null, 
>  [To] int not null,
>  PRIMARY KEY ([From],[To])
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into yourtable 
> ([From],[To]) values
> (2,3),(3,5),(5,4)
> ,(14,12),(12,15),(15,11),(11,10)
> ,(12,9)
> ,(21,23)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> ;WITH RCTE_CHAINS AS
> (
>   -- seeding with the start of chains
>   SELECT [From] AS MinFrom, [From], [To], 0 AS Lvl
>   , CAST(IIF(EXISTS(
>       SELECT 1 FROM YourTable n
>       WHERE n.[From] = t.[To]
>       ),1,0) AS BIT) AS hasNext
>   FROM YourTable t
>   WHERE NOT EXISTS
>   (
>     SELECT 1
>     FROM YourTable t2
>     WHERE t2.[To] = t.[From]
>   )
>
>   UNION ALL
>
>   -- looping through the childs
>   SELECT c.MinFrom, t.[From], t.[To], c.Lvl+1
>   , CAST(IIF(EXISTS(
>       SELECT 1 FROM YourTable n
>       WHERE n.[From] = t.[To]
>       ),1,0) AS BIT) AS hasNext
>   FROM RCTE_CHAINS c
>   JOIN YourTable t ON t.[From] = c.[To]
>
> )
> SELECT MinFrom AS [From], [To]
> FROM RCTE_CHAINS
> WHERE hasNext = 0
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> From | To
> ---: | -:
>   21 | 23
>   14 |  9
>   14 | 10
>    2 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c47db62a8874918b55a92bbe78c3681b)*